# How to get from Frankfurt-Hahn airport (HHN) to Frankfurt am Main International Airport (FRA)?

Tags: airport-transfer, germany, fra, hhn

I have found a flight from Frankfurt International airport (FRA), but from my city only Ryanair flies to Frankfurt-Hahn (HHN). The problem is that one airport is [114 km from the other](https://maps.google.es/maps?saddr=L193,%2056850%20Hahn,%20Alemania&daddr=Frankfurt%20International%20Airport,%20Frankfurt,%20Germany&hl=es&sll=49.382315,7.93966&sspn=2.413839,5.597534&geocode=FS4r-gIdlsluACnxASMUqSK-RzEKY61v24Fbtw;FRyD-wIdNaGCACEKEKPpO_uMyw&oq=frankfurt%20international&gl=es&mra=ls&t=m&z=10). What's the cheapest way to go from one to the other? (I have time)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally I would suggest looking for a different routing - as you've discovered Frankfurt-Hahn airport is a very long distance away from both Frankfurt itself, as well as from Frankfurt am Main airport.

If you do decide to go ahead with this connection, there is a bus service that runs between the two airports, run by [BOHR](http://omnibusse.bohr.de/routes/wtc/routes.php?action=detail&route_id=24&language=en).  Travel time is 90 minutes, and cost is currently 14 Euro per person each way.

Comment: The fact is that Ryanair fly directly to Hahn for 35 € and any other company takes a connection and is about 230 €. The difference is to high. Anyway, this shuttle is perfect for me. Do you know if I can buy the return ticket if the return is one month later? It says "24 houres" and I don't know what does it means... only return tickets for the same day?

Comment: Return appears to be for return tickets within 24 hours, so I'm guessing you'll need to pay for 2x one-way tickets.  Worth asking when you buy your ticket to confirm though.

Comment: The 20 EUR return ticket is only valid for 24 hours. There is no need to buy tickets in advance. Just buy them on the bus.